# checkstyle maximum method length not working on groovy

Tags: groovy, checkstyle

I have a checkstyle rule that limits the maximum method length. It doesn't seem to work correctly on groovy files and I suspect it has to do with how closures are handled by checkstyle.

In general, does checkstyle work well on groovy or are there other tools more geared toward groovy files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend using [CodeNarc](http://codenarc.sourceforge.net/) for checking Groovy code. It is designed for this purpose. The rule [MethodSize](http://codenarc.sourceforge.net/codenarc-rules-size.html#MethodSize) is the specific rule you should use.

Using Checkstyle is a bad idea as it cannot understand the Groovy syntax, as it is a super set of the Java language. It would definitely fail to parse closures.

Comment: +1 btw: kind of duplicate question, but same answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525652/groovy-code-analysis-tool